how to override the ButtonHTMLAttributes.type enums?
I'm developing a cross-platform app via uni-app (this is a solution to build a cross-platform app by Vue)
the type attribute of button has been changed in uni-app
which the value can only be in
"default" | "primary" | "warn";

instead of the ButtonHTMLAttributes.types default enum
"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined

but there will be an error in vscode since I use primary as the value of type


Type '"primary"' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.ts-plugin(2322)
runtime-dom.d.ts(430, 5): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes & ReservedProps & Record<string, unknown>'

I want to prevent the error wavy lines showing in vscode

What I've tried:
adding a uni.d.ts
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'vue';

declare module '@vue/runtime-dom' {
    interface ButtonHTMLAttributes {
        type?: 'default' | 'primary' | 'warn';
    }
}

I used thought this would expand the type of ButtonHTMLAttributes in node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.d.ts, but it didn't work.
